# Using shell_exec to create output file adds 2 questions marks to the end of filename

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am very very new to PHP, so I appreciate the patience and assistance.

For the following block of code, for some reason two question marks (`??`) are being appended to the end of the filename of the output file when it is created on disk.

So instead of the filename being something like:

`valueOFarg1_valueOFarg2_valueOFarg3`

it ends up being:

`valueOFarg1_valueOFarg2_valueOFarg3??`

(emphasis on the trailing questions marks)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$arg1_TEST1 = $_REQUEST['arg1'];
$arg2_TEST2 = $_REQUEST['arg2'];
$arg3_TEST3 = $_REQUEST['arg3'];

shell_exec('#!/bin/bash
FILENAME='.$arg1_TEST1.'_'.$arg2_TEST2.'_'.$arg3_TEST3.'
date > ./$FILENAME
echo '.$arg1_TEST1.':'.$arg2_TEST2.':'.$arg3_TEST3.' >> ./$FILENAME
date >> ./$FILENAME
exit');
?>
```

And I'm using **PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze15**

Comment: How are the values for `$arg1_TEST1`, `$arg2_TEST2`. `$arg3_TEST3` determined?  That is likely where your problem lies.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the problem since the values of these arguments are successfully written to the output file without the 2 questions marks...if I correctly understand what you are saying.  Thank you for your response.